# How to correctly write multiple meta tag using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Helo, I'm very raw in JS. I want to ask about my code, how to write it correctly?

```
function impScript(scriptURL){
   let headTitle = document.querySelector('head');
   let setProperty = document.createElement('script');
   setProperty.setAttribute('href',scriptURL);
   headTitle.appendChild(setProperty);
}
const metaScript = ['ar.js','ar2.js']
impScript(metaScript);
```

the code is working, but it resulting

```
<script href="ar.js,ar2.js"></script>
```

I'm hopping to make it like this

```
<script href="ar.js"></script>
<script href="ar2.js"></script>
```

how can I do it?
your answer will be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: `metaScript` is an array ... `impScript` doesn't expect an Array

Comment: yes you right. But my personal problem is, untill now I still confuse working with arrays.. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the array and create the tag one by one:

```
metaScript.forEach(s => impScript(s));
```

Comment: now I have another question, can you tell me why it results <script href="ar.js"></script> and followed with <script undefine=undefine></script> when use nested array?

the script is working fine, its just followed up by undefine

Comment: this is my array code :

var metaName = [];
metaName[0] = setMetaName('rel','shortcut icon','href','favicon.ico');
metaName[1] = setMetaName('property','og:site_name','content','Company');

Comment: @RedFrog, the issue is not quite clear.....but for nested array you have to use nested loop.

Comment: Its not, I don't know how to explain it in simple way. but I think I already fix it, I use .include instead of .forEach I don't know if it's a correct ways but it works